# The system cannot find the file specified java

Tags: java, cmd, java-io

Yes, I already know this question is a duplicate, but just bear with me here. None of the other questions answered this.

This is my code:

```
package pc.setup;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectoryCreator {
    public static void setupDirectories() throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd\\");
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd\": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at pc.setup.DirectoryCreator.setupDirectories(DirectoryCreator.java:7)
    at pc.load.PieClickerRunner.main(PieClickerRunner.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: What operating system are you running your code on?

Comment: Great!!! my code example will work for you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers. They were wordy, though, so in this answer I will try to summarize it.

When you call `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`, you must specify what shell you are using (only on Windows). So, you would say `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("command here", "cmd.exe")`. As you probably know, CMD is the Windows command shell for modern Windows operating systems.

Once again, thank you for your answers.

Comment: But exec method does not have (String, String) constructor.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here:

- cd is not an executable on its own; it is a built-in of the command shell.  `exec` only runs executables (in their own files).  That is why it is not found.  `exec` can run a command shell, but ...
- Even if you did change directory in a command shell, that change is only in effect for the newly spawned process, not for the program that launched it.

Sorry, but that approach does not work in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are running this application under Windows operating systems family (otherwise you will have to adapt it a little bit). The `Runtime.exec()` method is used to execute executable commands. It is not the case with `dir,` `cd,` `copy,` ... As a consequence of this it triggers an exception which is what you are experiencing.

The `cd` command is part of the windows command interpreter `cmd.` It can either be executed with `command.com` or `cmd.exe` depending on the version of the operating system.

Therefore we should run the command interpreter first and feed it the user - supplied command (such as `dir,` `cd,` `copy,` ...)

Here is a program that does that. It checks the `os.name` environment variable in order to select the right command interpreter. I test for Windows NT and Windows 95. If none of these two is found but is still a Windows operating system, then I assume it is a modern windows (such as Windows 7 or Windows 8) and it is using `cmd.exe.`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class StreamGobbler extends Thread
{
    InputStream is;
    String type;

    StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type)
    {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line=null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(type + ">" + line);    
         } catch (IOException ioe)
         {
            ioe.printStackTrace();  
         }
    }
}
public class GoodWindowsExec
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if (args.length < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("USAGE: java GoodWindowsExec <cmd>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try
        {            
            String osName = System.getProperty("os.name" );
            System.out.println("OS NAME IS " + osName);
            String[] cmd = new String[3];
            if( osName.equals( "Windows NT" ) )
            {
                cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
                cmd[1] = "/C" ;
                cmd[2] = args[0];
            }
            else if( osName.equals( "Windows 95" ) )
            {
                cmd[0] = "command.com" ;
                cmd[1] = "/C" ;
                cmd[2] = args[0];
            } else if (osName.toUpperCase().trim().contains("WINDOWS")) {
                cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
                cmd[1] = "/C" ;
                cmd[2] = args[0];
            }

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            System.out.println("Execing " + cmd[0] + " " + cmd[1] 
                           + " " + cmd[2]);
            Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
            // any error message?
            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
                StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");            

            // any output?
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new 
                StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

            // kick them off
            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            // any error???
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);        
        } catch (Throwable t)
          {
            t.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Here is a Simple runner for this class

```
public class GoodWindowsExecRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //GoodWindowsExec.main(new String[] {"dir *.*"});
        GoodWindowsExec.main(new String[] {"cd .."});
    }

}
```

Here is the result from executing the "cd .." command

[image: cd command]

Here is the result from executing a "dir *.*" command

[image]

There is an excellent article on java world called [When Runtime.exec won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2)

Comment: All very well but starting a command shell just to execute `cd` still won't accomplish anything useful.

Comment: @EJP, isn't that what Lucas asked about? If I answered his question I see no valid reason for you to downvote my answer

Comment: If it was not something usefull I doubt that anyone would have written a many pages article about it on javaworld and many other articles on various web sites